# How to write a .htaccess file for sub domains which built with codeigniter framework

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, ssl-certificate, subdomain

My client have a domain called "**https://buzzbehind.com/**" (Main Domain).  Also there are some sub domains. One of the sub domain url is "http://buzzmembers.buzzbehind.com" (BuzzMembers).

Actually a main domain and sub domains are having SSL certificates. So all of them working when we hitting url with "https" except BuzzMembers".

If I tried to hit the URL of BuzzMembers with https , it is showing me the layout of different sub domain BuzzAdmin32 of Main Domain. But the url is correct.

Htaccess file of Buzzbehind(Main Domain):

```
DirectoryIndex home.php index.html index.htm index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(promotionalpage)/(index)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ https://buzz.buzzbehind.com/promotionalpage/index/$3/$4/$5/ [r=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(productdetails)/(index)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ https://buzz.buzzbehind.com/productdetails/index/$3/$4/$5/?current_url=https://buzz.buzzbehind.com/promotionalpage/index/$4/$3/$5 [r=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Htaccess file of BuzzMember:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1    [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```

Htacess of BuzzAdmin32:

```
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]

</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.buzzadmin32\.buzzbehind\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/buzzadmin32\.buzzbehind\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

I need to run the BuzzMembers site with https. Now it is working only with http. 
Kindly advice me.

BuzzMembers Framework : Codeigniter

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean you need to have https://buzzmembers.buzzbehind.com to serve properly with SSL (green, not red, on the address bar), right? Then you need either a certificate containing this hostname or you need a wild card certificate *.buzzbehind.com to serve everything. Its nothing to deal with what framework you use on the server.

Comment: @KenCheung  Kindly check this link -> https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=buzzmembers.buzzbehind.com/

Comment: @KenCheung I checked all settings about the SSL is good. But it is something about the .htaccess i hope.

Comment: Actually I use a browser to visit https://buzzmembers.buzzbehind.com/ and I can see your login page. What's the problem?  I've also try to login and it gets back to the login page again with URI /login which sounds like everything works fine.

Comment: @KenCheung No. That is not a correct page. The real page is should be look like http://buzzmembers.buzzbehind.com. If you use the https instead of http, then you will see login form. the login form page is not correct.

Comment: @Karthink Rajan are you sure you have a separate <VirtualHost *:443> with ServerName buzzmembers.buzzbehind.com and DocumentRoot points to the correct place? VirtualHost settings for HTTP (*:80) and HTTPS (*:443) are configured separately.

Answer (score 1):

Add RewriteBase /buzzmembers.

you can use this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /buzzmembers
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: As per your suggestion, i just added the line "RewriteBase /buzzmembers" with my BuzzMembers .htaccess file. 

But it is now working. Did you represent the folder name on "/buzzmembers" ? is it a folder name or anything?

Comment: its the folder name. if my code works mark my answer as right(tick my answer)

Comment: if buzzmembers is your subdomain,then just add the code i given in .htaccess. just that 5 lines only.

Comment: @YadhuBabu subdomain didn't mean a subfolder under the DocumentRoot. They're different.  From the question I guess the httpd was configured with VirtualHost and each hostname having it's own DocumentRoot.

Comment: @Yadhu  Yes I tried with your 5 lines only. But it is not working. Am also confusing.

Comment: subdomain didn't mean a subfolder under the DocumentRoot. They're different. From the question I guess the httpd was configured with VirtualHost and each hostname having it's own DocumentRoot

**--> Kindly write the correct htaccess. Please. Then i will try with that.**

Comment: what is the base url you given for the subdomain. check it what you have used is it https or http//

Comment: I gave it in dynamic mode. If the sub domain have the server port is 443 then i will use the https with base url. else http i use.

`define("SSL_Prefix",($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? 'https' : 'http'));`

Comment: in your config.php file you add ~https://buzzmembers.buzzbehind.com/ as baseurl and check

Comment: @YadhuBabu Instead of that we can give the url on address as like we want. Those are same. Anyway i tried that too Yadhu. Not solved yet.

Comment: @KarthikRajan I discussed this issue with my friend who is a server admin. he asked to contact your Hosting support provider. it is Https
Ssl isue

Comment: @YadhuBabu Thanks . Yes I will contact support team. Thanks Yadhu for your effort.

Comment: @KarthikRajan ip might be different in ssl. That may be the issue

Comment: @YadhuBabu No Yadhu. Its like ip is 72.167.141.74 for all sub domain and domains are same. So the ip of SSL is not a problem . Check with **https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=buzzmembers.buzzbehind.com/ (https not working)

https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=buzzadmin32.buzzbehind.com/  (https not working)**